# Having trouble accessing functions from other files in C++

Tags: c++, debugging

I have just started learning c++ and right now i'm trying to use object oriented programming.  I have read from other articles that I needed to make a header class for the file with the function and include it into all the files using the function.  However whenever I try to put the function in the code runs but it does not run properly.  My function uses the sqrt method of math.h to square root a number I input.  I know I could just use this in the main() but I wanted to test OOP.  When I use sqrt in the main method my program works but when I put it in the other file my program spits out the same number I put in.
Heres my Code

Source.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Source2.h"




int main(){
    using namespace std;
    cout << "Please enter the number you want to root." << endl;
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    function1(x);
    cout << x;

}
```

Source2.cpp

```
#include <math.h>

int function1(int n){
int sqrt(n);
return n;
}
```

Source2.h

```
#ifndef _SOURCE2_H
#define _SOURCE2_H

int function1(int n);

#endif
```

This code works just not the way its supposed to.  so you could call it a bug I have.  If you enter a number like 4 my program should give the square root which is 2.
Help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You're not creating a class, and this isn't object oriented programming.  You're creating a function, which qualifies as procedural programming, and since it's in a separate file or compilation unit, modular programming.

Comment: Which C++ book are you learning from?

Comment: your `Source2.cpp` should include `Source2.h`

Comment: Thank you guys for your help.  I must admit I am pretty dumb because I realized this is not OOP.  I am just coming from Java I so bear with me.  I am so used to Java using "classname.function" to do this.  I was learning from a book and thought I would just challenge myself and instead of putting the sqrt method in the main file I would put in another .cpp.

Comment: @user3144018: It's good that you try these things. :)

Answer (score 4):

> My function uses the sqrt method of math.h to square root a number I input.

No, it doesn't.

It declares an `int` called `sqrt`, initialised with the value `n`, then promptly ignores this new `int`.

```
int sqrt(n);   // this is the same as `int sqrt = n;`
return n;
```

Did you mean:

```
return sqrt(n);
```

So this has nothing to do with "other files" or anything like that: you're simply failing to actually call `sqrt` due to a syntax typo.

---

Similarly, when you call `function1`, you don't do anything with the result.

```
function1(x);
```

Instead of this, write:

```
x = function1(x);
```

---

You should also be made aware that this is *not* object-oriented programming.

Comment: I thought this too but visual studio tells me that more than one instance of overloaded function sqrt matches the argument list.

Comment: @user3144018: That is not a reason to break your syntax to the extent that you're not calling `sqrt` at all; it's a reason to investigate that problem on its own. Programming by guessing doesn't work!

Comment: I figured it out.  I had to declare my "n" variable as a double, float, or long double in order for this to work.  Probably because square roots do not always end in perfect integers.

Comment: @user3144018: Well, not really. It's the input that has to be floating point (and they all convert equally from `int`, hence the ambiguity). The output is _always_ floating-point. In C++11 there are overloads accepting `int` arguments so you don't have to cast to floating-point inputs.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really object oriented programming in this example, but this should fix the function:

```
int function1(int n){
    n = sqrt(n);
    return n;
}
```

sqrt RETURNS a value, it doesn't modify the value passed in, so you need to store that value somewhere. I've opted to re-use `n` here.

And main:

```
int main(){
    using namespace std;
    cout << "Please enter the number you want to root." << endl;
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    x = function1(x);
    cout << x;

}
```

Again, `function1()` returns a value, so that needs to be stored. All `main()` does at present is echo the input value back to you.

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually using the result of `function`. Try `x = function1(x);` or `cout << function1(x);`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is you're not calling sqrt(n). The documentation for sqrt is here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/sqrt/

Basically what you're doing in Source2.cpp is called sqrt(n), but nothing is catching the return value. What you want to do is:

```
int function1(int n)
{
    int result = sqrt(n);

    return result;
}
```

I hope I helped!

Comment: No, basically he's not calling `sqrt` at all!

Comment: When I do this it tells me that more than one instance of overloaded function sqrt matches the argument list:
            function "sqrt(double _X)"
            function "sqrt(float _X)"
            function "sqrt(long double _X)"
            argument types are: (int)

Answer (score 0):

This should work,

source2.h

```
#ifndef _SOURCE2_H
#define _SOURCE2_H

#include <math.h>

// Class Definition - Object Oriented Programming
class MyClass
{

public:
    // Function Definition - Get the Sqrt
    double function1(double n);

};

#endif
```

source2.cpp

```
#include "source2.h"

// Referencing the function inside the class
double MyClass :: function1(double n){
    double a = sqrt(n);
    return a;
}
```

source.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Source2.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int x;
    cout << "Please enter the number you want to root." << endl;
    cin >> x;
    cout << "The number entered is " << x << " And the sq rt of the same is "; 
    MyClass c;      // Create an instance of MyClass , OOPS
    cout << c.function1(x); 
    return 0;   // Success Condition
}
```

Feel Free to ask me any questions, This is a bare minimum C++ Code that I could think of for your requirements. Do go through the comments above they are valuable from understanding perspective.